# How can I get ID of dropped images, this id will be sent to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, drag-and-drop

I have problem. I created base with football player and football ground with divs where they will dropped.

Screenshot >> http://www.dodaj.rs/f/3x/Jl/1Ee0tb6P/teren.jpg

**jQuery**:
I found simple drag and drop code on youtube tutorial.

```
    function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("img", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

    var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("img");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

**HTML:**
I organized positions into table without border, maybe, html code acts confused.

```
<form action="" method="post">

            <div class="teren">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="mid"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="def"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="for"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="mid"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="def"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="gk"></div></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="for"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="mid"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="def"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="mid"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="def"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Pošalji" name="btnPosalji"/>

            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you use the jQueryUI drggable/droppable widgets, the events passed to the event handlers contains all information about the elements involved.

Comment: You have the `id` of the dropped image, that's what you're storing in the `image` variable in the `drop()` function.

Comment: How can I use this id from drop() function?